# Which import mechanism is faster?

Tags: python, python-internals

1:

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
import math
math.sin(math.pi/2)

1000000 loops, best of 3: 284 ns per loop
```

2:

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
from math import sin, pi
sin(pi/2)

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 µs per loop
```

Comment: importing 2 small things vs an entire library.  Thats why it is best to really only import what you need for a file or application, otherwise there could be longer load times, etc

Comment: How many times I've you tried it? We're talking about 0.1 of a second or less. If the computer did something else at that time, it can affect the results drastically.

Comment: actually, the import step is just name binding in Python after the first imprt in a process (and Math is imported at interpreter startup. So it is 2 name binding vs 1 name binding  - it _could_ be this)

Comment: "How many times I've you tried it? " - 10 million times, as can be seen in the question's snippets.

Comment: This is because you are timing the import as well. Like @Fallenreaper said, you are importing a whole library instead of small pieces of it. If you were to only time the methods and not their imports then I would imagine it would be the same.

Comment: I took the actual sin call out of the equation, and it looks like "from" imports are just way slower.  TIL.

Comment: @Fallenreaper and Kevin Welch: your argument would mean that "importing the entire library" is slower. If you look at the timings that case is _faster_. Importing a single name `from` a module will import the module itself in python.

Comment: I wonder if this is somehow related to the new module `__getattr__` feature.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing the question title to better reflect the question.

Comment: @Fallenreaper.  Anything to back up your import whole library assertion?  AFAIK import consists of locating the file, executing all “unprotected module code” of it, i.e. anything not under a ‘def’ or a falsey if.   Then the namespace is bound to the importer.  For 2 functions or a whole bunch, the main cost is mostly going to be module-level code parsing and execution.  In fact the import just binds 1 ref - the module name.  we’re not talking ‘from x import *’ here.

Answer (score 4):

There you are timing two different statements - and indeed, "common sense" has it that attribute lookup as in the first snippet should have a higher overhead than using local (in this case, global) scoped names.

What is happening though, is that when one does `from math import sin, pi`, those two names have to be binded in the global scope where the import statement is, and in current Python it turns out the overhead for this binding far surpasses the overhead of binding just the name `math` in the other example.

This difference is more likely due to different code-paths inside the import machinery itself, when using `from <module>  import <name>` form instead of `import <module>` - keep in mind the times measured are really tiny in both cases.  And if you were calling `sin` as little as 3 times in the measured code, the difference would be supplanted already.

Comment: In my timings it also takes the store name out of the picture.  It's something deeper in the import machinery, not the name binding.

Comment: Yes - just some path way in the `import from` - don't forget that all it needs is a 3-4 lines of code as "heavy" as calling `math.sin` . Fact is no import statement will be in a tight-loop in a performance sensitive context (or at least should not be).

Answer (score 3):

The question is a useful reminder that a naive approach to benchmarking is unlikely to yield useful results. There are enough mistaken assumptions (as well as some answers) in the comments that the answer should perhaps be summarised.

First and foremost, importing individual names from a module does not mean the interpreter only loads a part of the library. The difference between the different forms of import is solely in how the imported entities appear in the importing namespace.

- `import module` results in the named module being imported (and added to `sys.modules`). It is then bound to the name `module` in the local namespace
- `import module as name` is exactly the same except it binds the newly-imported module as `name` rather than that of the module
- `from module import name` again imports the module and adds it to `sys.modules`, but does not bind it in the local namespace. Instead `name` in the local namespace is bound to the same object that `name` is bound to in the module.
- `from module import name as name2` works in the same way, but binds to `name2` in the local namespace the object that is bound to `name` in the module.

Secondly, the first (and only the first) import of a module requires the interpreter to load the module's code (and possibly compile the `.py` file if no corresponding `.pyc` can be found). Thereafter its presence is the `sys.modules` dictionary inhibits further imports - there's no point reloading code already in memory.

A "better" benchmark might therefore be (this code is untested: *caveat emptor*)

```
import math
from math import sin, pi
```

followed by

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
__main__.math.sin(__main__.math.pi/2)
```

and

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
__main__.sin(__main__.pi/2)
```

Casting the code in this way removes the first import from the timing, and leaves the only difference in timing down to the additional length of time it takes to implement the extra namespace lookups in the first test. While that is a useful thing to learn, it did not directly answer your question, since the differences in timing were not related to the import mechanism.

Finally, it's wise not to obsess about such timings (I understand this was an investigation, and there's nothing wrong with that). The time to look at optimisation is when you already *have* a working solution, and *only* when it needs to run faster!

A sound understanding of Python's import mechanisms will stand you in good stead as your Python skills develop.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the `sin` call out of the equation, it would seem that the `IMPORT_FROM` op is just more expensive.

```
>>> %%timeit -n 1000000
... import math; sin = math.sin; del math
...
144 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> %%timeit -n 1000000
... from math import sin
...
788 ns ± 0.824 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Disassembly of the two different kinds of imports shows the extra CPython opcodes for IMPORT_FROM:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("import modname")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (modname)
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (modname)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("from modname import funcname")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('funcname',))
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (modname)
              6 IMPORT_FROM              1 (funcname)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (funcname)
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Please do not take this as a recommendation to rewrite all your `from` imports in order to shave off nanoseconds.

Comment: "Please do not take this as a recommendation to rewrite all your from imports in order to shave off nanoseconds." - that is the most important part in this answer!