# Is it best to use "From x import x" rather than just importing a whole library?

Tags: python

Just curious as to what best practice dictates. I would assume that importing the whole library would make your code slower?

Comment: Actually from imports are slower (see: [Which import mechanism is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57483703/674039)), but it doesn't matter in practice. Both forms import the entire module regardless. There is no best practice here, it just depends what names you want to bring into your namespace.

Comment: The whole module needs to be initialized either way.

Comment: "Is it best" calls for an opinion, which is not what stack overflow is for. Better ask, "what is the difference..."

Comment: @wim "from numpy import array" doesn't put "numpy" in the namespace of REPL.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of import speed, it doesn't matter. The whole module is *always* imported; all `from x import y` does is de-namespace and limit the number of names you *see*, but the entire module is loaded and cached (in `sys.modules`).

`from x import y` makes it trivially faster to access `y` at time of use and obviously shorter to type than `x.y`, but it's not a big enough difference to be worth considering in 99.9% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

For packages written by someone else, it depends on how much you want to clutter your namespace. For example:

```
from foo import SomeFancyClass
from os.path import join
from numpy import array, inv, reshape, abs, linalg
import numpy as np
```

Importing a single descriptive name such as `SomeFancyClass` makes sense. But a generic name like `join` rather not, because 200 lines down in your code it will not be very obvious what kind of join function it was. If there are many names, like with `numpy`, it's definitely better to import the whole module (and moreover, `abs` from numpy will shadow the builtin `abs`).

If you write your own packages, you typically need to use this syntax:

```
from .modulename import foo
from . import modulename as mod
```

where `modulename.py` is another file within your package. This won't work:

```
import .modulename as mod # illegal
```

Comment: You can do `from . import modulename`, though.

Comment: Oh thank you @user2357112supportsMonica ! I didn't know - this syntax appeared first in the docs of Python 3.7.